# javax.jdo.JDODetachedFieldAccessException JDO app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I am getting the following error:

javax.jdo.JDODetachedFieldAccessException: You have just attempted to access field "admin" yet this field was not detached when you detached the object. Either dont access this field, or detach it when detaching the object.

Here I have a list of Store objects having an Admin fields as a subclass.

I am first calling this function

```
static List<Store> getStores() {

  PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

  Query query = pm.newQuery(XZStore.class);
  List<Store> stores = (List<Store>) query.execute();
  //need to detatch them here
  stores = (List<Store>) pm.detachCopyAll(stores);
  pm.close();
  return stores;    
}
```

and then accessing each one of the stores' admin field (store.admin).

I thought if I detachCopyAll(stores) then I also detatch the members of the
elements of stores. Is it not so?

I even tried the following but no luck:

```
for (Store store : stores)
  store.setAdmin(pm.detachCopy(store.getAdmin()));
```

Thanks,

John Goche

I finally found the solution. The following worked for me
(detaching the container element did not detach the member
element and I had to do it separately).

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

Query query = pm.newQuery(Store.class);
List<Store> stores = (List<Store>) query.execute();
//need to detatch them here
List<Store> detachedStores = new ArrayList<Store>();
for (Store store : stores) {
  Store detachedStore = pm.detachCopy(store);
  AdminUser detachedAdmin = pm.detachCopy(store.getAdmin());
  detachedStore.setAdmin(detachedAdmin);
  detachedStores.add(detachedStore);
}

pm.close();
```

Regards,

John Goche

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought that a read of JDO docs and the JDO spec would benefit you more, particularly sections like fetch plans/groups, and default fetch group. Your "solution" is inefficient.

Comment: Well, before separating entities in different entity groups I would like to get this simple example working first if at all possible... and in particular when do I need to detach stuff, anytime after making it persistent if I need to access it again?

Comment: The default fetch group is not letting me fetch a multivalued property.